# Block of data to Lines of data

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, csv

I have an array containg blocks of text data that are parsed to an CSV:

```
"Cecilia Elisabeth Arvidsson"
"Kungsvägen 118 A 35244 VÄXJÖ"
"Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ"
1969-06-17
0735372562,
"Pär Davidsson"
"Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ"
"Myntvägen 8 35260 VÄXJÖ"
1980-05-22
0709171505,
```

I want to transforms these blocks to simple text lines, so they easily can be imported to excell:

```
"Cecilia Elisabeth Arvidsson Kungsvägen 118 A 35244 VÄXJÖ Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ 1969-06-17 0735372562",
"Pär Davidsson Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ Myntvägen 8 35260 VÄXJÖ 1980-05-22 0709171505",
```

How can I accomplish this?

Here is my PHP-code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $gatunamn = $_POST['gata'];
    $ort = $_POST['omrade'];
    $csv_data = array();



    $newSpider->fetchPage($gatunamn, $ort, $offset=0);
    $obj = json_decode($newSpider->html);


    echo "<div id='rightcontent'><table id='one-column-emphasis'>";
    echo "<th><input type='checkbox' name='csv_all' id='csv_all'></th><th>Namn</th><th>Adress</th><th>Adress2</th><th>Adress3</th><th>Personnummer</th><th>Telefonnummer</th><th>Telefonnummer2</th>";
    $antal_sidor = round($obj->search->wp->totalHits / $obj->search->wp->pageSize); 
    echo "<td></td>";
    foreach($obj->search->wp->features as $fish) //Loopar ut 50st (pageSize)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='csv' class='csv'></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $fish->name . "</td>";
        $csv_data[] .= $fish->name;

        foreach($fish->addresses as $ad)
        {
            echo "<td>" . $ad->label . " " . $ad->postcode . " " . $ad->area . "</td>";
            $csv_data[] .= $ad->label . " " . $ad->postcode . " " . $ad->area;
        }   
        if(!empty($fish->dateOfBirth))
        {
            $convert_date = substr($fish->dateOfBirth, 0, -3); //Gör om datum från timestamp
            echo "<td>" . date("Y-m-d", $convert_date) . "</td>";
            $convert_datee = date("Y-m-d", $convert_date);
            $csv_data[] .= $convert_datee;


        }
        if(!empty($fish->phoneNumbers))
        {
            foreach($fish->phoneNumbers as $ph)
            {
                echo "<td>" . $ph . "</td>";
                $csv_data[] .= $ph . ",";

            }
        }       

        echo "</tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>";
    $j = 0;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $antal_sidor; $i++)
    {
        echo  "<a href='curl.php?gatunamn=$gatunamn&ort=$ort&offset=$j'>" . $i . "</a> ";
        $j += 100;
    }
    echo "</div>";
    /*echo "<div id='debug'><pre>"; 
        var_dump($obj);
    echo "</pre></div>";*/

    }
    if(isset($_POST['export']))
    {

        $fp = fopen("eniro.csv","w");
        fputcsv($fp,$csv_data,"\n");

        echo "<div id='csv_info'>";
        echo "<a href='eniro.csv'>Hämta CSV-fil</a>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

}
```

EDIT: I updated my question with the relevant code.

Comment: Please only post the relevant part of your code. See http://www.sscce.org

Comment: @AmalMurali: I have now updated my question.

Comment: Do i get you right that you have at the moment 2 arrays containing multiple items ( blocks ) and you want to have an array of lines?

Comment: @user500468: Did you read the link I gave you in the previous comment? There's still a big chunk of code, much of it unrelated to the issue at hand.

Comment: @Mario: I have just one array, called $csv_data, that contains block of text, as u can see in my example. I want that blocks to be lines instead.

AmalMurali: I allways gets complains when I paste short amounts of my code, so now I paste a little more instead :-). The code I pasted now is related to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not completely sure what you would like to archive but i wrote this little script that does what you named in your examples:

```
// Lets say you recive your data as a string:
$blocks = '
"Cecilia Elisabeth Arvidsson"
"Kungsvägen 118 A 35244 VÄXJÖ"
"Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ"
1969-06-17
0735372562,
"Pär Davidsson"
"Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ"
"Myntvägen 8 35260 VÄXJÖ"
1980-05-22
0709171505,';

// Then we can simply explode your data by the comma separator
$blocks = explode( ",", $blocks );

// loop trough the items and format the text blocks.
foreach( $blocks as $key => $block )
{
    $blocks[$key] = trim( str_replace( "\n", ' ', str_replace( '"', '', $block ) ) );
}

$blocks = array_filter( $blocks );

// Will result:
// Array
// (
//    [0] => Cecilia Elisabeth Arvidsson Kungsvägen 118 A 35244 VÄXJÖ Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ 1969-06-17 0735372562
//    [1] => Pär Davidsson Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ Myntvägen 8 35260 VÄXJÖ 1980-05-22 0709171505
// )

// At the end you can implode your data again to match your example.
echo '"'.implode( '",'."\n".'"', $blocks ).'"'."\n";

// Will result:
// "Cecilia Elisabeth Arvidsson Kungsvägen 118 A 35244 VÄXJÖ Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ 1969-06-17 0735372562",
// "Pär Davidsson Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ Myntvägen 8 35260 VÄXJÖ 1980-05-22 0709171505"
```

---

#### Update

```
// with the following data you deliverd: http://pastebin.com/ThAbhpkZ using here as $data

$array_of_blocks = explode( ',', implode( ' ', $data ) );

// Will result:
// Array
// (
//    [0] => Cecilia Elisabeth Arvidsson Kungsvägen 118 A 35244 VÄXJÖ Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ 1969-06-17 0735372562
//    [1] => Pär Davidsson Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ Myntvägen 8 35260 VÄXJÖ 1980-05-22 0709171505
// )


// At the end you can implode your data again to match your example.
echo '"'.implode( '",'."\n".'"', $blocks ).'"'."\n";

// Will result:
// "Cecilia Elisabeth Arvidsson Kungsvägen 118 A 35244 VÄXJÖ Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ 1969-06-17 0735372562",
// "Pär Davidsson Skolgatan 1 B 35233 VÄXJÖ Myntvägen 8 35260 VÄXJÖ 1980-05-22 0709171505"
```

Comment: You are using a string in your explode. But I have an array, not a string. How can I use your code with array, instead of string?

Comment: @user500468 Please tell me exactly how your array looks like (var_dump / print_r ) then i can help you :)

Comment: @user500468 I updated my answer try it out and tell if it's what you where searching for.

Comment: Is $data an array? Because I must use an array in implode?

Comment: Yes $data is the array of your pastebin

Comment: Im getting an error: Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/curl2.php on line 287 Here is my PHP: http://pastebin.com/rKig7sGK

Comment: You can't just write an array to a file you have to serialise it. Do this: $bis = '"'.implode( '",'."\n".'"', $array_of_blocks ).'"'."\n"; instead of $bis = array($array_of_blocks);

Comment: Thank you for your time to help me. It works pretty fine now. :-). One more thing, you can the the content of my CSV-file here: http://pastebin.com/ALwvT8FE As you can see, it contains of many "-characters. How can I reduce this characters to only contains 2 per line, like this "line1", "line2". Hope you understand me :)

Comment: @user500468 can you paste me the code where you generate these strings?

Comment: I think the easiest thing you could do is something like this: http://pastebin.com/YzMeAuR9

Comment: Or you could pass $array_of_blocks directly to fputcsv

Answer (score 0):

```php
$vStringlist = implode(' ', $csv_data)
```

This way you'll have an array, containing each of your block as single line, concatenated by whitespace.

Comment: is it possible and better to concatenate by "\n" or "\r\n" carriage return instead? Because he seems want to preserve structure by adding space between the data.

Comment: @stixxx: How can I make a newline after every line. I don't want they to appear beside each other.

Comment: @user500468 It seems you want to print it directly as html, so you can implode the `$vStringList` with `"<br>"` as 'glue'.

Comment: @stixxx: How do you mean? I want it to be simple text lines in the csv file with newlines.

Comment: @user500468 In this case, implode this array with new line control caracters `$vCSV = implode("\n", $vStringlist);`

Comment: @stixxx: That dont work.. The lines are not seperated with new lines. Here is my code:   $fp = fopen("eniro.csv","w");
  $vStringlist = implode(' ', $csv_data);
  $bis = array("\n", $vStringlist);
  fputcsv($fp,$bis);

Comment: @stixxx: Any other idea? :)